# why array.length + 1 returns NaN

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

i am trying to add to the value of length i got from array.length using a for loop as below but it keeps returning NaN

```
lent;
 ndat:any;

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
 this.afs.collection('Courses').doc(`${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`).collection('courses').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {

      console.log('my data',data); 
      this.ndat= data;

  this.lent=this.ndat.length;
  console.log('my lenthyyyyy',this.lent);

  });

 for (let i = 0; i < this.dat.length; i++) {
      console.log(i+this.lent);
      this.ref2=this.afs.collection('Courses').doc(`${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`).collection('courses').doc(`Course ${this.lent+i}`);
        this.ref2.set({
          name: this.dat[i],
          progress:'In Progress',
          duration:'time'


       });
       }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell if you you don't tell use what `this` and `array` are and the context around these calls. In your example, there's no need to store `array.length` into `this`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like array.length is not defined.  To reproduce:

```js
var array = {}; // no length property
console.log(array.length + 1); // NaN
```

Where do you set 'array' and 'dat'?

Comment: I got the solution, the for loop was executing before getting the length, so i removed the for loop from the contructor and created a function for it